# Bypass x-frame-options for clickjacking

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability, clickjacking

Is there any way to bypass the x-frame-options header without using a MitM or changing the packets in another way?

So actually getting a site that has x-frame-options: DENY to be shown in an iframe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is one caveat when using `X-Frame-Options` header: [it only checks the top level frame](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/07/20/block-iframe-loading/). This means that if you have nested frames, i.e. frames within frames, it is still possible for another origin to include a site with a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header.

In this regard the header `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'` is better, because it checks *all* frame ancestors.

[image: frame within frame]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very clear. Just one question to clarify something: This only works in the same domain right? So from a different domain it would still be impossible to load the site in an iframe?

Comment: @Arminius You are right. I was confusing DENY and SAMEORIGIN. The scenario I described is possible with SAMEORIGIN, not with DENY.

Answer (score 1):

> So actually getting a site that has x-frame-options: DENY to be shown in an iframe.

It's not possible to embed a site sending an `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header in any frame.

From [RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034):

```
   DENY
      A browser receiving content with this header field MUST NOT
      display this content in any frame.
```

However, it might in some instances be possible to bypass the `SAMEORIGIN` directive as some browsers only check the top-level origin and not the direct frame parent:

```
   SAMEORIGIN
      A browser receiving content with this header field MUST NOT
      display this content in any frame from a page of different origin
      than the content itself. [...]

      Please note that current implementations vary on the
      interpretation of this criteria.  In some, it only allows a page
      to be framed if the origin of the top-level browsing context is
      identical to the origin of the content using the X-Frame-Options
      directive; in others, it may consider the origin of the framing
      page instead.
```

(Emphasis my own.)